# undefined method `signed_id' for "sdsd":String - Active Storage

Tags: rails-admin, rails-activestorage

I'm having an issue using rails-admin and Active Storage at the same time. I saw that you can modify the value of labels with the label method. For example, for the "user #1" thing:

```
def name
  email
end
```

The problem is that I have an Asset model to upload multiple files, but I see this:

[Ugly attachment id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Bue.png)

If I try to do the same trick (just to see if every file is now called "sdsd"):

```
def files
  'sdsd'
end
```

Then this shows up:
[undefined method `signed_id' for "sdsd":String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjtZW.png)

I tried making a reset of the database but it didn't work at all. Any ideas? I just want to show every filename instead of that ugly id's.

Comment: Probably the files method is already taken by another private API. It looks that way, its a common name.

Comment: I think that's not the case, if I do this:
    def files
      puts "blabla"
    end
This doesn't show the files part in rails-admin but prints "blabla" in the console.